# How to find all instances of an event NOT happening within 0-1 days of another event happening?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have one dataframe of transportation, and another dataframe of records at a location.

I want to find all instances where someone took transportation and was NOT on record at the location within 0-1 days of the transit. Below is a simplified example of what I have, and a method I have tried. The method/reason is not relevant to compare by, but I need it in my actual data, so I included a column in each dataframe.

The trouble is coming in when accounting for 0-1 days within transit. If someone takes transit on 1/4, and is on record at the location 1/5, then that is a non-issue. Even if I add additional date rows to imagine that the person travelled on 1/5 as well, then 1/4 would still show up as an NA when I do the join. Any ideas?

```
library(tidyverse)

Date <- c("2022-01-01","2022-01-02","2022-01-03","2022-01-04","2022-01-04","2022-01-05", "2022-01-06")
Method <- c("train","taxi","train","bus","bus","bus", "train")
Person <- c("A","B","C", "D", "E", "F", "G")

transportation <- data.frame(Date,Name,Person)

transportation

Date2 <- c("2022-01-01","2022-01-02","2022-01-03","2022-01-05")
Reason <- c("x","Y","Z","W")
Person2 <- c("A","B","C", "D")

location <- data.frame(Date2,Reason,Person2)
location

# This WORKS and finds instances of someone traveling to the area, but not being on record at the location
location %>% 
  right_join(transportation, by = c("Date2" = "Date", "Person2" = "Person"))

# But what if the person was on record THE NEXT DAY at the location?
# Looking at Person D in the location dataset - they traveled on 1/4/2022 and were at the location on 1/5/2022.
# This is a non-issue, but I am not sure how to do it
# I tried adding an extra rows for the following date, HOWEVER, this has the issue of flagging 1/4 as a problem still
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is

```
transportation %>% 
  left_join(location, by = c("Person"="Person2")) %>% 
  filter(as.Date(Date2) != as.Date(Date) & as.Date(Date2) != as.Date(Date) + 1 
         | is.na(Date2))
```

Comment: I just tried that and it returned nothing, but it should return person E, F, and G from the first dataframe. It did help me in the right direction though, but I will have to post a new question w/ more problems I found

Comment: Ok, i modified it.